# Remote Access Using Windows 8

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have remote access to dual monitors in work, but hve a single monitor at home (Windows 8). I cannot access the secondary screen from home. What are my options?

Comment: What type of "Remote access" are you using exactly?  Window's RDP doesn't care about actual "Monitors" on the host, as your RDP session get's its own desktop that matches the client's monitor configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use Windows remote desktop which ignores how many monitors you have and sets the resolution to the monitor you're streaming to or you can use a program like[Teamviewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) which allows you to change which monitor you look at or allows you to view both of them at once.